# django template for loop some table rows display only once

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Model:

```
class Subject (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

In my sql table i have more than 50 users and everyone have assigned one day of a week (ie. user1 -> MON, user2 -> MON, user3 -> WED ...)

In template below I want to display table with Days and Subject names, 
but I want to **display day names only once** as a head of a users group.

```
<table>
<tr class="head"><th>SUBJECTS</th></tr>

{% for field in subjects_all %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <tr class="head"><td colspan=5 align="center">MONDAY</td></tr>
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.day == "MON"  %}
    <tr><td>{{ field.name }}</td></tr>
    {% endif %}

    {% if ... } # <- ???
    <tr class="head"><td colspan=5 align="center">TUESDAY</td></tr>
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.day == "TUE"  %}

    <tr><td>{{ field.name }}</td></tr>

    {% endif %}

    (...)

{% endfor %}

</table>
```

In example belowe I know I can display Monday only once using forloop.first,
but how can I display rest of days **only once** at top of a group of users ?
If I do normal 'if' , TUESDAY will display on top of every single user
found in database and that's not what I want.

**EDIT:**
And I want to avoid copying whole for loop 7 times for every day in a week

Comment: Have you tried [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)? you could sort them once they are ordered. You will need to do this in the view

Comment: Yes I'm using order_by() but it just sorts all users by day, and this is not my problem. It won't help with display day only once for every users group

Comment: I would change how you are using the for loops. I would cycle through each day of the week and print out all the users under that

Comment: can you show a piece of code how would you use it ? I must admit i don't understand how to use cycle in templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag.

Alternatively, you could use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) to group the items into days.